# Elements added by replace() aren't clickable, even with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm trying to use `.replace` to create some spans that I can click later:

```
mytext.replace("someword","<span class='clickme'>someword</span>")
```

It does correctly create the spans, but I can't get them to trigger jQ events. I've tried:

```
$(document).on("click",".clickme",function(){
    alert("meow")
})
```

But that also doesn't work, feels like I'm missing something.

Comment: What is `mytext`? - Do you ever re-append to the DOM? Have you inspected to verify those spans are actually there?

Comment: Can you re-create the issue with a jsFiddle.net example or stack snippet?

Comment: after you use `replace()` do you actually insert the html? Show more code

Comment: Something is wrong in the pretext of your question because the delegated form of `.on()` which you show works just fine with dynamically created content.  My guess is that you aren't actually modifying the DOM like you think you are.  Show the rest of that code if you want further help.  Better yet, reproduce your simple problem in a jsFiddle.

Comment: Working example on JSFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/dowa8nhr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you reapply the replaced text to the element from where you have sampled the text :)

```js
var mytext = $('p').text(),
    changes = mytext.replace("someword","<span class='clickme'>someword</span>");

$('p').html(changes);

$(document).on("click",".clickme",function(){
    alert("meow");
})
```

```css
.clickme{
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor someword sit amet</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSBIN
http://jsbin.com/hejefayebi/1/edit?html,js,output

Well what happens is that you're not adding the replaced text as html to the page.

See, when you use the "replace" function of the string object, you're manipulating text, just that, text, the [replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string with the manipulated text, you need to insert that text into the html somehow.

i.e. if you replace foo in the following text:

```
var justText = "Hi I'm foo"; // Just some text
// First the replace function returns a new string, it does not modify the original string, so you have to reassign the value
justText = justText.replace("foo", "<span>foo</span>"); // replace will return "Hi I'm <span>foo</span>", but you need to assign it.
// Assign the text to a paragraph
var p = document.getElementById("paragraph");
// Then because you want to insert new HTML DOM elements into an existing element
// you have to use either the "innerHTML" property of HTML elements, or the "html" jQuery function (which use innerHTML internaly);
p.innerHTML = justText; // Once you have inserted the DOM elements, the click bindings will be attached.
```